# Android navigation graph resets onResume

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a single activity application that uses Android's Navigation Component to navigate between fragments.

I have an issue where, if the app is backgrounded and resumed, the navigation graph returns to the `startDestination`. Shouldn't the state of the graph (i.e the current fragment) be retained?

Below is a sample of my setup.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: MainActivityBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
} }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/root_navigation" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

root_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <!-- Fragments and actions..... -->
</navigation>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you change `android:id="@+id/root_navigation.xml"` to `android:id="@+id/root_navigation"`?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work as well @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Now I wonder how you go away from the splash screen to whatever destination comes first

Comment: @EpicPandaForce in the end it was a very simple fix. Since `MainActivity` used be the splash activity before we refactored into a single activity application, it had `android:noHistory=true` set in the Manifest which was causing this behaviour.